# Получить все дни между датами sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, дата

```
NomerDoc    Код Филиала          StartDate         StopDate
3209         Fil            01.04.2017 0:00      30.04.2017 0:00
3491         Fil1           01.04.2017 0:00      30.04.2017 0:00
3378         Fil2           01.04.2017 0:00      30.04.2017 0:00
3398         Fil3           01.04.2017 0:00      30.04.2017 0:00
```

мне неоходимо получить такую же  таблицу только на каждый день в промежутке между startdate и stopdate

Comment: Придётся использовать дополнительную опорную таблицу чисел (возможно, синтетическую), где их не меньше, чем дней в самом длительном промежутке. Ну и DATEADD().

Comment: Уточните, какую СУБД вы используйте, это сильно повлияет на ответ.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c.DATE as [DAY],[NomerDoc]
   ,dm.[StartDate]
  ,dm.[StopDate]
FROM [Calendar] c
 join [Table1] DM on (dm.[StartDate]<=c.[Date] and dm.[StopDate]>=c.[date])
```

Создал еще одну таблицу с датами на каджый день и соединил с исходной таблицей